# Autoclipping multi-line flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to show 8-9 cards in a nice table with 2-4 rows and 2-4 elements per row. All rows have the same amount of elements.

I.e. depending on width of container element user should see ether 8 or 9 cards:

```
C1 C2 C3 C4
C5 C6 C7 C8
```

or

```
C1 C2 C3
C4 C5 C6
C7 C8 C9
```

or

```
C1 C2
C3 C4
C5 C6
C7 C8
```

How can I do it with out media queries?

The most natural way seems to be flexbox with `flex-wrap: wrap`, but how to explain flexbox that I need to hide a row if it contains only 1 element? Are there css only solution? Can I detect with javascript how many lines a wrapping flexbox has?

Comment: What's wrong with media queries, they are an **essential** component of responsive design/

Comment: @Paulie_D, Media queries will work unpredictably, since flexbox container can take an arbitrary part of the page. You need container queries here, not media queries, but container queries are not a part of current CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox combined with `flex-wrap: wrap` and media-queries can be a good solution for this.

You can set up several breakpoints and create a different behavior for different screen sizes. That can be (apart from setting `flex-basis`) also hiding the last element with `display: none`

With mobile-first approach you could do it for example like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrapper div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
.wrapper div:last-child {
  display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper div {
    flex-basis: 33.33%;
  }
  .wrapper div:last-child {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .wrapper div {
    flex-basis: 25%;
  }
  .wrapper div:last-child {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>C1</div>
  <div>C2</div>
  <div>C3</div>
  <div>C4</div>
  <div>C5</div>
  <div>C6</div>
  <div>C7</div>
  <div>C8</div>
  <div>C9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: amazing. this is art

Comment: I'm sorry, but I specifically asked "How can I do it with out media queries?". Media queries won't work predictably if your wrapper takes an arbitrary part of the page.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was confused by the typo ("without" is written together)... Anyway I don't know your exact implementation, but with MQ you can also control the width of the wrapper (depending on the viewport width) and make sure it will work as intended. That would not be sufficient?

Comment: @TomasKorinek, what do you mean? I need my container elements be the width they are already are, independently of their inner content, including this solution for the table. Card table must fit perfectly into the elements I put it into, and the width of those elements and it's dependence on media queries are already decided.

Comment: Just one more time: the card table layout must depend on the width of the element, which contains the card table, not the width of the page. This is the problem I'm asking solution for.

Comment: @klm123 Ok, I understand. But since we don't have widely supported container queries yet, I am trying to find some workaround, which could work with MQ... Now I understand your container should have the same width it already has... But still you should be able to find some relation between container width and screen size, no?

Comment: @TomasKorinek, may be I can do it now, even though the formula will be very complex, but I can't do it every single time the relation changes. Not to mention that there can be two different card containers on the page at the same time. Inner implementation of the container must be independent of the rest of the site design, or I will waste hundreds, if not thousand hours supporting this small piece of code it afterwards. I'm not going to go this route.

Comment: @klm123 Ok, you can check my other answer here then.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to use container queries, but unfortunately they are not widely supported now in 2021. Apart from that I am not aware of CSS-only solution for this exact issue without media queries.

I still believe media queries are a good solution for this (in the case you are able to find relation between viewport width and container width), but since you are insisting on NOT using them, your only way is to use some javascript (although it might not be a good idea to have layout dependent on JS).

One way for that would be to use one of already made libraries (e.g. [EQCSS](https://elementqueries.com/)), but in case you want to have your own solution, you can simulate the container queries for example like this.

```js
$(function() {
  updateWrapper(); // call on page load
  $(window).on('resize', function(){
    updateWrapper(); // update on window resize
  });
});

function updateWrapper() {
  var innerWrapper = $('.wrapper > div'); // get inner wrapper
  innerWrapper.removeClass(); // remove previously set class

  var elWidth = $('.wrapper').width(); // get container width
  if(elWidth < 600) { // set class according to container width
    innerWrapper.addClass('mobile');
  } else if (elWidth >= 600 && elWidth < 992) {
    innerWrapper.addClass('tablet');
  } else {
    innerWrapper.addClass('desktop');
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  /* width: 400px; // use any value here */
  background: lightgray;
}
.wrapper > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.mobile div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
.mobile div:last-child {
  display: none;
}

.tablet div {
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
}
.tablet div:last-child {
  display: block;
}

.desktop div {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}
.desktop div:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div>C1</div>
    <div>C2</div>
    <div>C3</div>
    <div>C4</div>
    <div>C5</div>
    <div>C6</div>
    <div>C7</div>
    <div>C8</div>
    <div>C9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you decide to observe the row count in JavaScrpt, the layout is easy to accomplish with javascript (whatever, you will finally use JavaScript so I think that is not worthy to be  galling).
If not, use a media query to control the display of elements, and use **grid** instead of flexbox, in this way:

Document structure:

```
.container
  #card1.card
  #card2.card
  ...
  #card8.card
  #card9.card
```

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
@media all and (min-width: 600px){
  .container{
    grid-template: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .card:last-child{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

and so on for others...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I specifically asked "How can I do it with out media queries?".